# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, resource given in

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to search in a file if an ip is already there with in_array. but I get this error
`Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, resource given in`.

```
  var $RATES_RESULT_FILE = "results.txt";
  function writeResult($item,$rate){
     $ip     = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'); // ip looks like an usual ip 127.0.0.1..
     $f = fopen($this->RATES_RESULT_FILE,"a+");
    if(!in_array($ip, $f)) {
     if ($f != null) {      
        fwrite($f,$item.':::'.$ip.':::'.$rate."\n");
        fclose($f);
     }
    }
  }
```

`fwrite` looks in English like this: $f,String:::127.0.0.1::: 5 (scale 1-5 votes)

It seams that is recognizing the file as a resource instead of an array, is there anyway to convert the file from resource to array.
Final results.txt file looks smth like this:

```
String:::41.68.178.78:::3
String:::41.68.178.78:::2
String:::41.68.178.78:::1
String:::175.68.178.78:::5
```

Comment: `$f` is not an array, so doing an `in_array()` on it isn't going to work. `fopen()` doesn't actually read any data; it just opens the file in preparation to be read.

Comment: Why do you think PHP will magically return array from `fopen()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Doge's answer, you will first need to construct your array. This can be done using `array_map` on the array given to you by `file` to parse out the IP address. However it may be easier to do this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($this->RATES_RESULT_FILE);
if( strpos($contents,$ip) === false) {
    $contents .= $item.":::".$ip.":::".$rate."\n";
    file_put_contents($this->RATES_RESULT_FILE, $contents);
}
```

However, this can get quite memory-intensive, especially if the file gets large. A more memory-friendly way would be something like:

```
exec("grep -F ".escapeshellarg($ip)." ".escapeshellarg($this->RATES_RESULT_FILE),
                                                            $_, $exitcode);
// I use $_ to indicate a variable we're not interested in

if( $exitcode == 1) { // grep fails - means there was no match
// or use $exitcode > 0 to allow for error conditions like file not found
    $handle = fopen($this->RATES_RESULT_FILE,"ab");
    fputs($handle, $item.":::".$ip.":::".$rate."\n");
    fclose($handle);
}
```

EDIT: `exec`-based replacement for `fopen/fputs/fclose`:

```
    exec("echo ".escapeshellarg($item.":::".$ip.":::".$rate."\n")." >> "
                                    .escapeshellarg($this->RATES_RESULT_FILE));
```

Comment: Glad I could help - I just edited in an exec-based replacement for the file manipulation, this may be faster and more resilient to race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = fopen($this->RATES_RESULT_FILE,"a+");
if(!in_array($ip, $f)) {
```

`$f` is a file resource not an array.

Did you maybe intend `file` instead?

```
$f = file($this->RATES_RESULT_FILE);
if(!in_array($ip, $f)) {
```